# Find users with most number of common pages they liked

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to find pairs of users who liked the same pages and list the ones who have the most common page likes at the top.

For simplicity I am considering the following table schema

```
Likes (LikeID,  UserID)

LikeDetail (LikeDetailID,   LikeID, PageID)
```

I am trying to find pairs of users with most number of common page likes ordered descending. E.g User1 and User2 have liked 3 pages in common.

I would to have the resulting set of the query to be

```
UserID1 UserID2 NoOfCommonLikes
2       3       10
4       3       8
1       5       4
```

I am guessing it would need aggregation, join and aliases however I needed to rename a table twice using AS which did not work for me.

Any tip would be appreciated in MySQL, or SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server and MySQL 8+, you can use a CTE which `JOIN`s the `Likes` and `LikeDetail` table, and then self-JOIN that where `PageID` is the same but `UserID` is not, and then grouping on the two userID values:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT l.UserId, d.PageID
 FROM Likes l
 JOIN LikeDetail d ON d.LikeID = l.likeID)
SELECT l1.UserId AS UserID1, l2.UserID AS UserID2, COUNT(*) AS NoOfCommonLikes
FROM CTE l1
JOIN CTE l2 ON  l2.PageID = l1.PageID AND l2.UserID < l1.UserID
GROUP BY l1.UserID, l2.UserID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

In versions of MySQL prior to 8.0, you need to repeat the CTE defintion twice in a `JOIN` to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT l1.UserId AS UserID1, l2.UserID AS UserID2, COUNT(*) AS NoOfCommonLikes
FROM (SELECT l.UserId, d.PageID
      FROM Likes l
      JOIN LikeDetail d ON d.LikeID = l.likeID) l1
JOIN (SELECT l.UserId, d.PageID
      FROM Likes l
      JOIN LikeDetail d ON d.LikeID = l.likeID) l2 ON l2.PageID = l1.PageID AND l2.UserID < l1.UserID
GROUP BY l1.UserID, l2.UserID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Note that we use `<` in the UserID comparison rather than `!=` to avoid getting duplicate rows (e.g. for `(UserID1, UserID2) = (1, 2)` and `(UserID1, UserID2) = (2, 1)`.

I've made a small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad786c9f30cc11eac752f0a75dc2d440) which demonstrate the queries.